# ¿Como imprimir un documento sin vista previa, usando el sitio de producción desde el cliente?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, pdf, servidor

Cuando imprimir documentos pdf desde localhost, no tengo ningun problema, la forma que lo hago es la siguiente:

```
public static void imprimir(string fileName, bool borrar = false)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = fileName;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();
        //p.WaitForInputIdle();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        try
        {
            if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                p.Kill();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionRegister("imprimir", ex);
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando imprimo usando la aplicación web de producción, me sale el siguiente error:

**"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"No hay ninguna aplicación asociada con el archivo especificado para esta operación","exceptionType":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception","stackTrace":" en System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)**

Yo deduzco que está tratando de imprimir desde alguna impresora del servidor, pero obviamente no estoy desde el servidor, estoy en un pc(cliente), lo cual es lo normal, que tengo conectado a una impresora x.

¿Como podría solucionar este problema?¿Se entiende la pregunta?

Comment: `info.Arguments = "\"" + impresora + "\"";`  en este argumento estas apuntando a la dirección dentro de la red de la impresora?

Comment: Le mandaba el nombre de la impresora. Pero para simplificar la pregunta, elimine esa linea en la edición de la pregunta. Lo que hace, es imprimir la impresora por defecto, el problema radica cuando está en producción

Comment: @Danilo se entiende tu pregunta, ya van 3 preguntas relacionadas donde tratas de imprimir un documento PDF generado desde un `ReportViewer` y que quieres imprimirlo pero desde la impresora del cliente. Pero el código que pones en cada pregunta siempre va a funcionar en el servidor (cuando haces tus pruebas en localhost, es que tu PC se comporta como servidor local). _Vamos a resolver tu problema, pero para ello necesito que me indiques desde que evento se imprime el documento, ¿hay un botón de imprimir o es otro evento?_

Comment: Gracias por responder @Davlio, he tratado de buscar distintas formas de imprimir desde el sitio de producción, pero nada. Respondiendo a tus preguntas, para este caso particular, ¿desde que evento se imprime el documento?
desde un boton, guardo el pdf(veo que guardó bien) y la ruta donde quedo guardado lo envío a ese metodo:

imprimir("C\\documento.pdf", false);

Comment: Estuve leyendo por ahí, y dice los siguiente:
Funciona localmente porque el cliente y el servidor son la misma máquina y el código del servidor tiene acceso a los recursos del cliente. Una vez desplegado, el servidor y el cliente ya no son la misma máquina. No puede acceder a los recursos del cliente desde el código del servidor, no puede imprimir en la impresora local mediante el código del servidor. 

La verdad no quiero rendirme, se que debe haber alguna forma de lograr imprimir de forma directamente

Comment: @Davlio, al menos que existe alguna forma o estrategia de abrir el pdf, imprimirlo directamente y luego cerrarlo.

Comment: no. no hay forma.. tu codigo se ejecuta del lado del cliente y este codigo se ejecuta del lado del servidor. salvo que encuentres algun metodo por javascript o algo asi, no lo veo factible desde c#

Comment: Investigando, encontre algo, pero no se como se usa, o se instala los componentes requeridos.

https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-ESC-POS-commands-from-ASP-NET-directly-to-the-client-printer/

Answer (score 1):

Yo tengo el mismo problema ya llevo varios días, lo que hago es abrir el pdf y que el cliente seleccione su impresora e imprima, este es el código:

```
string pdfPath = Server.MapPath("~\\Guia\\pdf.pdf");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(pdfPath);
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Le he dado esa misma solución por ahora, generar vista previa, pero he visto puntos de ventas que imprimir directo.

Comment: además, he visto este ejemplo., pero no me resulta.

https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-ESC-POS-commands-from-ASP-NET-directly-to-the-client-printer/