# Imprimir directo sin vista previa con asp.net/javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de imprimir directamente a una impresora predeterminada. Lo que hago es mandar a imprimir con vista previa, ya que por ahora no puedo imprimir directo, ya que al subirlo a sitio de producción me salia errores que según algunas respuestas a mi pregunta, era que por seguridad no se puede enviar un proceso de imprimir desde el servido al pc del cliente([¿Como imprimir un documento sin vista previa, usando el sitio de producción desde el cliente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98067/como-imprimir-un-documento-sin-vista-previa-usando-el-sitio-de-producci%C3%B3n-desd/100167#100167))

Mi idea es que cuando se mande la instrucción para imprimir, se inhabilite el vista previa o se lo salte, para que así se pueda imprimir directamente, sin estar preguntando la impresora a imprimir. He visto que existen aplicaciones web que funcionan correctamente el imprimir tickets.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function PrintPanel() {
                var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
                var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
                printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
                printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
                printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                printWindow.document.close();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    printWindow.print();
                }, 500);
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat = "server">
        <asp:Panel id="pnlContents" runat = "server">
            <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight:bold; font-family: Arial">Hello,
                <br />
                This is <span style="color: #18B5F0">Mudassar Khan</span>.<br />
                Hoping that you are enjoying my articles!</span>
        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick = "return PrintPanel();" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Espero poder encontrar la solucion de saltarme el vista previa y así imprimir directamente sin necesidad de hacer alguna configuración en el navegador

Comment: Hola, tengo el mismo problema, encontraste la solucion?

Comment: Hola, si, la unica forma de hacerlo es instalar una aplicacion escritorio cliente que se comunique con el servidor, esto es mediante signalR. La aplicacion cliente se instala por cada caja o lugares de que se va a imprimir, si se imprime desde una misma caja, solo se necesita instalar una aplicacion cliente

Comment: Hola, @danilo me gustaria conocer mas acerca de tu respuesta que tipo de aplicacion?

Answer (score 1):

La única forma de hacerlo es instalar una aplicación escritorio cliente que se comunique con el servidor, esto es mediante signalR. La aplicación cliente se instala por cada caja o lugares de que se va a imprimir, si se imprime desde una misma caja, solo se necesita instalar una aplicación cliente

Comment: podrias compartir un poco mas sobre esto?

Comment: debes buscar un ejemplo de signalR, en donde una aplicación de escritorio, se comunique con una aplicación web mediante chat

Comment: tambien podrias hacer un api , que seria lo mas facil,y solo lo instalarias en el servidor o la pc que tenga acceso a las impresoras , envias una peticion desde cualquier cliente al servidor para que imprima